# Django test cases - How to call a javascript function from a .html for testing?

Tags: javascript, python, django, testing, testcase

I am trying to test a `javascript` function that is present in a `html` file. How can I call that specific function from `tests.py` (In `django`) ?

Comment: you can try [PyExecJS](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyExecJS)

Comment: @Mr.A OP is asking to test it in django, I guess

Answer (score 1):

By using the [splinter](http://splinter.readthedocs.org/en/0.7.2/) library or [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) you can test web applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) `webdriver`.
[Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) `webdriver` can test any url in a browser.

This is the most basic tutorial for finding an element in a browser:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("your_button_which_call_js_function")
elem.click()
```

`elem.click()` will call your javascript function and later you can trace its output on html itself.